# Inset Text Shadow

Tags: html, css

I'd like this reviewed.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/nehut/1/edit?html,css,output)

**HTML**

```html
<body>
    <!-- Introduction to the text shadow property -->
    <div class="container one">
       <h1>The Dark Knight</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- Show the inset shadow 'hack' -->
    <div class="container two">
       <h1>The Dark Knight Rises</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```css
    body{
        background: #424243;
        margin: 0;
    }
    h1{
        font-size: 5em;
        font-family: Georgia;
    }
    .container{
        padding: 20px 50px;
    }
    .one h1{
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: 4px 3px #222;
    }
    .two{
        background: #ccc;
    }
    .two h1{
        background-color: #222;
        color: transparent;
        text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -moz-background-clip: text;
                background-clip: text;
    }
```

Comment: It would really help to have a description of what you have there, what its purpose is, etc.

Comment: @user1668270 What makes you think the use of text-shadow is a hack?  Also, it is very helpful if you provide a demo (see: http://jsfiddle.net/, http://codepen.io/, etc.)

Comment: I've added a demo now. In light of the changes to the CSS it no longer seems like a hack. It did seem like one when I was clipping the h1 container background to fit the h1 text.

Comment: @user1668270 This isn't a hack, too. This is the purpose of `background-clip`. ;) Please add a description to your question, because our ways of reviewing are limited without one.

Answer (score 6):

1. You're using prefixed versions for the `background-clip` property. There is only a need for the `-webkit-` prefix here, so you have support for Android 2.x. You can omitt `-moz-`, unless you need to support Firefox 3.6.

   [Can I use CSS3 Background-image options?](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts)
2. It looks like you're trying to illustrate the styling of text with `text-shadow`. You probably want to use example text with a higher `font-size`. Instead of heading elements, you should be using `span`'s:

   ```
   <span class="demo-snippet">The Dark Knight</span>
   ```

   `h1`–`h6` are for headings and subheadings. In your case a heading would be something like *Usage of the text-shadow property*.
3. Use `0` instead of `0px`. You don't need to add the unit for zero values.

Other than that, I don't know what else one should review. I'll update my question, if you add some more information.

Comment: Thanks Kleinfreund. I've made some changes based on what you've said. I'm using the above for training material to demonstrate how to use the text-shadow property effectively.

Comment: @kleinfreund There's not enough content here to say whether or not the use of the headline element is appropriate.

Comment: @user1668270 I've rolled back your edit, because it would invalidate my answer. If you make some changes based on a review, you can update your question with new stuff, but only if you keep the old code as well.

Comment: @cimmanon I didn't say it's necessarily inappropriate in his case, but when he is using it for demonstration purposes (e.g. illustrating the effect of `text-shadow` on an element with a higher font-size).